# how to link http client with ApiResource

Tags: php, symfony, entity, api-platform.com

I have a client which gets xml and converts it to associative array:

```
class GetYukiAccountingBalance implements GetYukiAccountingBalanceInterface
{

   /**
     * @var HttpClientInterface
     */
    public static $balance;
    public static $succesfulResponse;
    public static $glAccountBalanceArray;

    private $httpClient;

    private const YUKI_API_URL = 'https://api.yukiworks.nl/ws/Accounting.asmx/GLAccountBalance';
    private const YUKI_API_HOST = 'https://api.yukiworks.nl';
    private $yukiApiKey;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient, SerializerInterface $serializer, $yukiApiKey)
    {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
        $this->yukiApiKey = $yukiApiKey;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    public function GLAccountBalance($administrationID, $sessionID, $transactionDate)
    {
        $response = $this->httpClient->request('GET', self::YUKI_API_URL, [
            'query'   => [
                'administrationID' => $administrationID,
                'sessionID' => $sessionID,
                'transactionDate' => $transactionDate
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'yukiapi-host' => self::YUKI_API_HOST,
                'api-key'  => $this->yukiApiKey
            ]
        ]);
        
                
    

        $data = [];
        $balance = GetYukiAccountingBalance::$balance;
        $balance = new SimpleXMLElement($response->getContent());
        
        
        foreach ($balance->GLAccount as $account) {
            $data[] = [
               'accountBalanceCode' => (string)$account->attributes()->Code ?? '',
               'accountBalanceType' => (string)$account->attributes()->BalanceType ?? '',
               'accountBalanceDescription' => (string)($account->Description ?? ''),
               'accountBalanceAmount' => (string)($account->Amount ?? '')
            ];
        
    }
}
```

I also have an entity with ApiRecourse() so i can put and store data to a database via open api dashboard

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\GLAccountBalanceRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *  shortName="glbalance", 
 *  collectionOperations = {
        "GET"={
            "openapi_context"={
                "summary"= "Retieves list of great ledger balances",
                "parameters"= {
 *                      {
 *                          "name"="glBalanceList",
 *                          "description"="List of great ledger balances stored in databse",
 *                          "default"="15000",
 *                          "in"="path",
 *                          "required"=true,
 *                          "type"="string"
 *                      }
 *                  },


            },
        } 
        },
    itemOperations ={
        "GET"

    },
   )

 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=GLAccountBalanceRepository::class)
 */
class GLAccountBalance
{
   
    /**
     * @ApiProperty(identifier=true,)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountBalanceDescription;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountBalanceAmount;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountBalanceCode;

    /**
     * @ApiProperty()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1, nullable=true)
     */
    private $accountBalanceType;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=User::class, mappedBy="glAccountBalance", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $users;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();

    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceDescription;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceDescription(?string $accountBalanceDescription): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceDescription = $accountBalanceDescription;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceAmount(): ?float
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceAmount;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceAmount(?float $accountBalanceAmount): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceAmount = $accountBalanceAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceCode;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceCode(?string $accountBalanceCode): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceCode = $accountBalanceCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAccountBalanceType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->accountBalanceType;
    }

    public function setAccountBalanceType(?string $accountBalanceType): self
    {
        $this->accountBalanceType = $accountBalanceType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|User[]
     */
    public function getUsers(): Collection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    public function addUser(User $user): self
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
            $user->addGlAccountBalance($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeUser(User $user): self
    {
        if ($this->users->removeElement($user)) {
            $user->removeGlAccountBalance($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see i can get a list of GLAccounts but i do not want to get data from the database, i want to directly get the content of the client from the open API dashboard. My question is how can i link the client with the entity and how can i specify that i want to get the content of client in the ApiResource() annotations.

Comment: Check api-platform's docs about `ouput` option and about data persisters or custom controllers, where you can inject you own service and return its response.

Comment: Can you please give me an example for my case, its really difficult how the input, output and custom controllers is explained in the api platform i don't understand it.

Comment: I don't know how i can first make an output and then a custom controller and connect those two and include it in ApiResource

Comment: Check the documentation about Data Providers.

Comment: Just create data provider and inject your logic in it.